# How can I remove MuiClockPicker-arrowSwitcher at my TimePicker component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with removing '<' and '>' at my `TimePicker` component. Here is my code example:

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
  <TimePicker
    {...field}
    openTo="hours"
    views={['hours']}
    inputFormat="HH:00"
    mask="__:__"
    value={closeTimeValue}
    onChange={(newValue) => handleCloseTimeChange(newValue)}
    components={{
      OpenPickerIcon: AccessTimeFilledIcon,
    }}
    InputAdornmentProps={{ position: 'start', variant: 'standard' }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} sx={{ width: '120px' }} />}
  />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

I tried to use overrides at `createTheme`

```
        MuiClockPicker: {
            styleOverrides: {
                arrowSwitcher: {
                    display: 'none',
                },
            },
        },
```

But it gives me an error

> TS2322: Type '{ MuiCheckbox: { styleOverrides: { colorPrimary: { color: string; }; }; }; MuiOutlinedInput: { styleOverrides: { root: { color: string; border: string; }; }; }; MuiInputLabel: { styleOverrides: { root: { color: string; backgroundColor: string; paddingRight: string; paddingLeft: string; }; }; }; ... 4 more ...; MuiCl...' is not assignable to type 'Components'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'MuiClockPicker' does not exist in type 'Components'.

Here is an image of `arrowSwitcher` that I want to remove

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code shoud work as expected:

```
<TimePicker
    {...field}
    openTo="hours"
    views={['hours']}
    inputFormat="HH:00"
    mask="__:__"
    value={closeTimeValue}
    onChange={(newValue) => handleCloseTimeChange(newValue)}
    components={{
      LeftArrowButton: Boolean,
      RightArrowButton: Boolean,
      OpenPickerIcon: AccessTimeFilledIcon,
    }}
    InputAdornmentProps={{ position: 'start', variant: 'standard' }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} sx={{ width: '120px' }} />}
  />
```

Comment: No, it would not. I receive an error: `TS2322: Type '{ OpenPickerIcon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">> & { muiName: string; }; LeftArrowButton: BooleanConstructor; RightArrowButton: BooleanConstructor; }' is not assignable to type '{ OpenPickerIcon?: ElementType<any>; }'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'LeftArrowButton' does not exist in type '{ OpenPickerIcon?: ElementType<any>; }'.`

Because components doc from `PureDateInput.d.ts` is `components?: { OpenPickerIcon?: React.ElementType; };

Comment: I created sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/localizedtimepicker-material-demo-forked-1xwr6t?file=/demo.js . Can you verify that this is what you want?

Comment: I could not say it is not correct, it was my fault to use "reactjs" tag under my post. Actually I using a typescript and after adding your suggestions I have those errors. https://codesandbox.io/s/localizedtimepicker-material-demo-forked-gr415f?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: I don't see any errors when running code in sandbox from url you provided

Comment: That's weird. I maid an image of it https://imgur.com/a/jpitlBS